# How can I get a real-time input via keyboard module?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import keyboard
def printPressedKey(e):
    print("key pressed  : {}".format(e.name))

keyboard.hook(printPressedKey)
keyboard.wait('esc')
```

this code prints pressed keys when I press esc. I want to print pressed keys as I press keys. How can I do this?

EDIT

This happens only when you execute python via nppexec in notepad++ so you just execute it on the console. Sorry for everyone ;(

Comment: It sounds like you are looking fora keylogger.  Maybe this will help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design-a-keylogger-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pyinput package,  it works well for both mouse and keyboard

https://pypi.org/project/pynput/